# Does or will exFAT support symlinks?

Tags: windows-7, mac, hard-drive, partitioning, exfat

I've just acquired a brand new laptop. Did split my ssd in 3 partitions, one for `win7`, one for `macOSX` and one shared `data` partition. I chose `exFAT` for this partition, but i did not find how to create symlinks on it.

With win7 `mklink` won't work. Any suggestions/ideas?

Should i have picked NFTS for this shared partition ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Symbolic links are nowhere referenced in the [exFAT feature list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914353.aspx). Additionally I remember that NTFS symbolic links only work if source and destination are NTFS partitions.

<s>May be it is sufficient to mount the shared exFAT data partitions as a sub-directory somewehere on the NTFS partition?</s>

Comment: Unfortunately mounting as a subfolder does not allow to create a symlink using `mklink.exe`

Answer (score 13):

**No**

> Soft links:
>
> - NTFS  Yes
> - UDF   Yes
> - exFAT No
> - FAT32 No

[Reference: File System Functionality Comparison](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison)

Comment: UDF **does** support symbolic links (soft links). See the UDF rev2.01 specification: http://www.osta.org/specs/pdf/udf201.pdf and another reference: http://www.diskinternals.com/glossary/udf.html

Comment: @leden Updated the answer to reflect the change