# Unexpected file modifications on external exFAT SSD

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssd, external-hard-drive

After moving an external drive from

I have a 1TB external SSD with a single exFAT partition. I plugged this into Mac OS X and write about 250GB worth of files. File contents seem normal. After safely ejecting the drive, and plugging it into an Ubuntu 14.04 system with `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed, the drive mounts successfully and I can see the files. However, many of the files now have extra data both appended and prepended. For example:

On Mac OS X:

```
$ cat bootstrap.bash
build/soong/bootstrap.bash
```

On Ubuntu:

```
$ cat bootstrap.bash
XSym
0026
b6fcaef0c9993fb6d1312e1d5e1749ef
build/soong/bootstrap.bash (Note: Tons of whitespace here...)
```

This has happened to thousands of files. Prefixed with `XSym`, a 4-digit number, and then what appears to be a hash (MD5 perhaps?). After the file contents, a large amount of space characters.

Another example:

```
$ cat build/envsetup.sh
XSym
0016
44d14bb79b8bd36de18d71e0498a4a19
make/envsetup.sh
```

**EDIT: The affected files may all be symlinks**

I'm looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288644/how-to-relink-these-symlinks-after-moving-the-system) to see if it answers my question...

Answer (score 1):

Answer found! These strange modifications are what Mac OS X chooses to do to represent symlinks on filesystems that do not natively support symlinks. Plugging the drive into any OS X results in these 'aliases' being resolved, but on Linux the exFAT driver does not interpret these files as symlinks, because the ExFAT filesystem standard [does not support symlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/232257/does-or-will-exfat-support-symlinks).

When trying to create a symlink on exfat using Ubuntu, the following error happens: `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘test/bootstrap.bash’: Function not implemented`. If I were to copy the entire external drive contents onto a different filesystem which supported symlinks, then I could use something like the answers shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288644/how-to-relink-these-symlinks-after-moving-the-system) to try and locate all of these mac os x workarounds and resolve them. That's no good for my purposes, so back to using a different filesystem